# Drupal - Drupal.settings values does not reload when validate fails

Tags: jquery, drupal, drupal-6

I have added the settings to my javascript file using this:

```
drupal_add_js(array('xc' => array('unit_descriptions' => $descriptions)), 'setting');
drupal_add_js(array('xc' => array('unit_names' => $units)), 'setting');
```

And it works fine when loading the .js file using:

```
$unitName.text(Drupal.settings.xc.unit_names[utid]);
$unitDesc.text(Drupal.settings.xc.unit_descriptions[utid]);
```

In order to load the values.
But when validation fails, e.g: if I dont specify a name or whatever, these two arrays disappears and I get the statement in the console:

```
Drupal.settings.xc is undefined
```

How can I reload these arrays, or prevent the on validation fail to remove the arrays.
Please, any help is appreciated.

Kind regards!

Comment: why not just check to see if xc is defined first before you do something?

Comment: Does validation fail when $descriptions or $units are empty? Also what output do you get when you view source for the place you expect this to be in the code?

Comment: I solved it, in the validate function I just checked for any errors, and if an error exists, I just add the js files again! Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it, in the validate function I just checked for any errors, and if an error exists, I just add the js files again.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $form['#after_build'][] = 'yourmodulename_after_build';

    function yourmodulename_after_build ($form, &$form_state) {
      //...do something...      
      return $form
    }
```

Use this "#after_build" in your hook_form or hook_form_alter, so your changes will be applied every time the form is shown (also after validation etc)